# Binding Control IsChecked in the code behind

Tags: c#, binding

I'm generating some elements of my user interface on the fly to prevent duplication of the same code across my windows as they are very similar on the design. One control that I'm generating is a toggle switch which is currently binding like this in xaml:

```
IsChecked="{Binding DebugEnabled, Source={StaticResource NotifyFields}}
```

How do I go about moving this into the c# code behind for when this control is generated?

```
var tsGeneratedSwitch = new ToggleSwitch
{
    Header = "View Information",
    OffLabel = "No",
    OnLabel = "Yes",
    IsChecked = False,
};
tsGeneratedSwitch.Checked += SwitchChanged;
tsGeneratedSwitch.Unchecked += SwitchChanged;
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myBinding = new Binding
{
    Source = NotifyFields,
    Path = new PropertyPath("DebugEnabled"),
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
};

BindingOperations.SetBinding(tsGeneratedSwitch, CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, myBinding);
```